# Running Spleeter on Docker: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.3.0

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, spleeter

I am getting the following error when I try to build my docker image:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 21.2.4 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

This is what my requirements.txt file is:

1. musdb
2. museval
3. Flask==1.1.1
4. gunicorn
5. flask_script
6. Flask-Migrate
7. spleeter

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
#Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
#Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat wget

# install dependencies
#RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

ENV MODEL_PATH /model
ARG MODEL=2stems
RUN mkdir -p /model/$MODEL \
    && wget -O /tmp/$MODEL.tar.gz https://github.com/deezer/spleeter/releases/download/v1.4.0/$MODEL.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvzf /tmp/$MODEL.tar.gz -C /model/$MODEL/ \
    && touch /model/$MODEL/.probe
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg libsndfile1
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install spleeter
RUN mkdir -p /app/uploads/
RUN mkdir -p /app/processed/
EXPOSE 5000
# copy project
COPY ./src /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Spleeter: https://github.com/deezer/spleeter

How do I fix this, please?

- I have tried updating my pip version to the latest but when I do that, it installs a long list of different dependencies, making the build runtime very long. The first time I cancelled it, it ran for about 2 hours.

My computer: MacBook Pro 2020 M1

Comment: Follow this link https://hub.docker.com/r/deezer/spleeter/